# How to draw "Find" result bar with keyboard shortcut in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

When you type in <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> in Sublime Text, you enter the "Find" mode, with the search result bar shows up on the bottom of the screen. However, I would like to return to the original form only with keyboard and not like to do mouseover to the X-mark on the result bar and then tap the x-mark to remove the search bar, which is quite a lot of work.

So is it feasible to return to the pre-search mode only with keyboard? I use Sublime Text 3 on my OS X 10.9.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape will close the find menu.